# echo and (var_dump or print_r) showing completely different things on laravel object

Tags: php, laravel, echo, var-dump

I have this code in laravel:

```
$languages = $languages->orderBy($sort_by,$sort_dir)
                ->take($limit)
                ->paginate($limit);

echo $languages->getCollection();
echo $languages->links();
```

These lines echo something but if I do

```
var_dump($languages->links())
```

I get a humongous recursive object that crashes my browser from how big it is

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: This is because of  var_dumps on an object gives you it's child and parent class attributes and value related information also.

Comment: laravel 5 handles better in this case. laravel 4 always crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 5 you should use `dd`, e.g.:

```php
dd($links);
```

or in view:

```blade
{{ dd($links) }}
```

`dd` will prevent those recursive warnings.

Comment: in laravel 4.2 ( the one I use ), dd crashes my browser by displaying a never-ending dump

Comment: [{{dump('string')}} in Laravel blade outputs value twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48731507/2943403)